# Including an image in the symfony transation file with assetic?

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I want to include an image in the symfony translation file with assetic, how can this be done?

```
<![CDATA[Some text<br><img scr=" generated url with assetic "><br>some text]]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use translation parameters. Instead real src in translation you should have parameter name.

```
<![CDATA[Some text<br><img scr="%variableName%"><br>some text]]>
```

Example usage in twig template

```
{{ "your.translation.with_parameter"|trans({'%variableName%': assetUrl}, "domain") }}
```

You can get your asset uri path from controller with this code:

```
$myAssetUrl = $this->container
    ->get('templating.helper.assets')
    ->getUrl('bundles/acmedemo/images/header.png');
```

Read more about assets helper in Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating/helpers/assetshelper.html

Comment: Thanks but I want to replace the place holder %variableName% in the controller instead-off in twig. I found some code but do not get it working, found the following: $this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl('images/header.png', 'Bundle/Resources/public'); This is to get the placeholder. Get the error that it is not an asset package?

Comment: I updated my answer with informations how to get asset url from controller/service.